# Bound on variance between realization and expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, concentration-of-measure

I'm looking for some bound on what feels like should be a concentration inequality, e.g. $F(n,\epsilon)$ where

$$\Pr\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\mathbb E[X]\right)^2 > \epsilon\right) \leq F(n,\epsilon)$$

Here, $X_i$ are i.i.d., and you can assum you know $|X_i| < X_\max$ always.

It's very similar to Bernstein's or Efron Stein, but it isn't. I feel like it should be super simple, but I can't seem to find it. Any pointers would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: It occurs to me that what I'm kind of looking for is some concentration on the variance of $X_i$. Therefore if I could impose this (say, $X_\max^2$). But, what is the concentration of the empirical variance to the true variance?

Edit: Note that I am NOT looking for

$$\Pr\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\mathbb E[X]\right)^2 > \epsilon\right) \leq F(n,\epsilon)$$

which you can do using a number of different concentration inequalities.

Edit: Ok I think my sleep deprived brain finally figured it out. The term

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\mathbb E[X]\right)^2  $$

is exactly the sample variance. Therefore there's no reason to believe it will diminish with large $n$. Therefore there's no real point in bounding it this way.

Nevermind, go ahead and close if you wish :)

Comment: As you mentioned, the empirical variance is converging to the true variance by LLN, so it will be more meaningful if you are discussing the probability like $\displaystyle \Pr\left\{\left|\frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - E[X])^2 - Var[X]\right| > \epsilon \right\}$ and for this probability, you have the Chebyshev's inequality to bound it. It will include a higher moment, but should be fine if you are already assuming the distribution is bounded.

Comment: Yeah ok I finally figured out that my question is fundamentally flawed, which I added to the edits.